# Actually referencing and using the image captured with HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html, image

I'm aware that this simply achieved by inserting

```
<input type="file" id="photo" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

what I'm having trouble with (due to my lack of proper coding skills) is actually grabbing and putting to use the image the user selects/takes.

Specifically, I want an iPad user to be able to grab an image which will be rendered on the page according to CSS. Once an image is there, I then want them to be able to replace that image with another if they need to.

Sounds simple enough but, once captured, I can't write the code I need to reference the image and manipulate it.

By the way, this is for an in-house project and so permissions etc. are irrelevant.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Messing with this today with some help off the web, I came up with the following which works and also changes the text of the button once an initial image has loaded.

```
<div id="zeroDiv">
<input type="file" id="getPic" accept="image/*">
</div>
<div id="picWrapper">
    <img id="image">
<div id="buttDiv">
    <button id="picButt"><span class="buttText">Insert image</span>
    </button>
</div>
</div>
```

and the JQuery/JavaScript:

```
$('#picButt').click(function () {
$('#getPic').trigger('click');
});

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#getPic").on("change", gotPic);
$("#image").load();
});

function gotPic(event) {
$("#image").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
$("#picButt span").text("Change image");
}
```

working fiddle with CSS at http://jsfiddle.net/1rg5Lyyk/4/

I'm now looking for a way to store the image in local storage once it's captured so that when the user moves away from the page and returns, the image returns too. But that's a different question!